# Why does the dot command (source) not work on files without path in zsh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I recently switched from bash to zsh. In bash, I used the dot alias `.` for the source command, e.g.

```
. .bashrc
```

It worked with `. .bashrc`, `. ~/.bashrc`, `. ./.bashrc`.

However with zsh, the dot alias does not work in the same way. It only works with a path to the file. But not if I use a file without path:

This does not work:

```
. .zshrc
```

It would give me this error: `.: no such file or directory: .zshrc`

But these all work:

```
source .zshrc
. ./.zshrc
. ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's actually [the standard behavior](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html) of the dot command: **it uses a $PATH search,** just like when running commands – not a regular relative path. So you can have your common libraries in e.g. ~/bin/ and simply load them with `. libwhatever.sh` from any directory.

Performing a direct relative path lookup is a nonstandard Bash extension.

(Similarly, dot `.` is actually the main command listed in the "shell language" standard, and `source` is a shell-specific alias – not the other way around.)

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity, is there a way to have the "bash" behavior with zsh?

Comment: Relative paths are accepted as long as they contain a slash, so `. ./.bashrc` would source from the current directory. The manual doesn't offer any option to exactly match bash behavior – you would have to either use `source` or put the current directory in $path (which is a poor idea).

Comment: @jost21: If you're really, really want bash's behavior you could write a wrapper function, something like that `function .() { [[ ! -f "$1" && -f "./$1" ]] && builtin . "./$1" || builtin . $@ }` -- this (untested) snippet does not however take arguments into account.

Comment: (It also doesn't account for the first `.` returning non-zero status and causing an unwanted fallback to the second `.`. Really, && || does not work the same way as a ternary operator.)

Comment: @grawity: Oh yes, good point, thanks! I should have known better, but was too lazy to write if .. then .. else.

Comment: If you want relative paths, you could always just `alias .=source`, but you'd lose the $PATH search

Comment: Adding the source from the Bash Reference Manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins): **When Bash is not in POSIX mode, it searches the current directory if filename is not found in $PATH.**